# Quitar el scroll vertical en html y bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola casi ya esta finalizada mi pagina estática, pero tengo un problema el `scroll` vertical lo noto insuficiente, pero cuando lo quito, ya no me funciona el `scroll` con el `mouse`, espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

este fue el código que coloco para eliminar la barra vertical pero ya no funciona el `scroll` con el `mouse`

Este la pagina, de paso me ayudan para que sea mas optimizada

[PAGINA WEB](http://lcnperusac.com/)

```
<style type="text/css">
            body{overflow-y:hidden;}
</style>
```

Comment: cuando dices que "lo notas insuficiente" te refieres a qué exactamente? debes formular mejor tu inquietud y compartir el código ´html´ para que sea mas fácil entender el problema y poder brindarte las posibles soluciones.

Comment: Quitar la barra de scroll vertical sin dejar de ser sroll con el mause, por otro lado la pregunta que citan no tiene una respuesta contundente

Answer (score 4):

Existe una pregunta similar a esta pero la respuesta que se registró no fue la correcta, lo que tienes que hacer es mediante un div en el body, agregas una clase css en donde habilites el scroll, y mediante la propiedad ***-webkit*** ocultas el scroll, algo asi: (al ejecutar el snippet, usa la rueda del mouse sobre el contenedor)

```css
.content {
     border: 1px dashed gray;
  padding: .5em;
  
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 5em;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* se habilita el scroll vertical */
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  /* solo oculta su visualizacion */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eu
urna et leo aliquet malesuada ut ac dolor. Fusce non arcu vel ligula
fermentum sodales a quis sapien. Sed imperdiet justo sit amet venenatis
egestas. Integer vitae tempor enim. In dapibus nisl sit amet purus congue
tincidunt. Morbi tincidunt ut eros in rutrum. Sed quam erat, faucibus
vel tempor et, elementum at tortor. Praesent ac libero at arcu eleifend
mollis ut eget sapien. Duis placerat suscipit eros, eu tempor tellus
facilisis a. Vivamus vulputate enim felis, a euismod diam elementum
non. Duis efficitur ac elit non placerat. Integer porta viverra nunc,
sed semper ipsum. Nam laoreet libero lacus.

Sed sit amet tincidunt felis. Sed imperdiet, nunc ut porta elementum,
eros mi egestas nibh, facilisis rutrum sapien dolor quis justo. Quisque
nec magna erat. Phasellus vehicula porttitor nulla et dictum. Sed
tincidunt scelerisque finibus. Maecenas consequat massa aliquam pretium
volutpat. Duis elementum magna vel velit elementum, ut scelerisque
odio faucibus.
</div>
```

Comment: Lo puedo colocar en el body en vez del div?

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores mmm no estoy seguro, yo te sugiero que manejes el contenido de tu sitio dentro de un div principal (.content) y no directamente desde el <body>